# In flight message transformation in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

For a requirement we are putting together following data pipe line.
IBM MQ (Source) -> Kafka Connect -> Streaming API (Kafka/Flink/Spark) -> DB (Sink).
I wanted to check is there any option to perform message encoding transformation (custom) at the Kafka Connect layer or before message reaches kafka/kafka connect cluster.
The option should not add significant latency to the data pipe line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are describing is Single Message Transform capability of Kafka Connect. Various transforms [ship with Apache Kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html), and you can [write your own](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html).